# Can we make specific grid lines invisible using Anychart Library?

Tags: anychart

I have created a chart using Anychart Library, I want to make the grid lines at 85 and 95 grades invisible.

[image]

When I am writing the following code statement it removes all lines from the chart:

```
chart.yGrid().enabled(false);
```

How can I remove specific lines from the grid?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get rid of unwanted grid lines.

One of the ways you can achieve this is by [specifying ticks on the Y axes](https://docs.anychart.com/Axes_and_Grids/Scales#array).

In this way, you will specify desired values as ticks, and the corresponding grid lines will be adjusted accordingly:

```
// Set wanted ticks.
yScale.ticks().set([-1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    
//Enable yGrid.
chart.yGrid().enabled(true)
```

Feel free to explore such method [in a playground](https://playground.anychart.com/riu757Ka)